# Why is calling source /path/to/my/file different in function than in ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: bash

I'd like to keep count of how many times I run a command, so I created a file to store the count. When I run `$ my_function`, the goal is to overwrite the file with a new value. So far, success. But subsequently calling `$ my_function` yields the same result and does not overwrite the file again.

If I close the command line and re-start it, things work fine. I'm trying to figure out why calling `$ source "$count_file_path"` at the end of `my_function` is not having the same effect as when I call it in `~/.bash_profile`. Any ideas?

`${HOME}/bash/.bash_count`

```
#!/bin/bash

declare MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT=0
```

In my ~/.bash_profile, I source the file. When I run the command, I want to increment it and write it to the file.

`${HOME}/bash/.bash_my_functions`

```
my_function () {
    local count_file_path="${HOME}/bash/.bash_count"

    local curr_count="$MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT"
    echo "curr_count: $curr_count"

    local incremented=$((curr_count+1))

    # Overwrite existing .bash_count file with new value
    printf '#!/bin/bash\n\ndeclare MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT=%s\n' "$incremented" > "$count_file_path"

    source "$count_file_path"

    cat "$count_file_path" # same result every time unless I quit and restart the command line
}
```

Comment: how to do invoke `my_function` ? add a sample transcrtipt of steps we can run to reproduce your problem

Comment: a more reliable way to keep a counter may be to read the value directly from the file and then immediately overwrite it, rather than reading from the environment. use file locking to avoid issues with multiple invocations trying to change the file at the same time (eg. see `flock`)

Comment: The obvious difference here is the context: `declare` has a different meaning when it's called within a function (wherein it creates a local variable rather than a global). Just assign with `MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT=0`, no `declare`.

Comment: (also, @jhnc is correct about locking -- if you don't use flock, which you should, _at least_ use the tempfile-and-rename pattern so your file isn't ever in a half-written state under its final name)

Comment: See https://replit.com/@CharlesDuffy2/DarkcyanCoarseAssembly#main.sh demonstrating that the code works correctly once you drop the `declare`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not `source` that has a different meaning called within a function -- it's `declare`.

If you want to make it always create a global variable, add the `-g` argument:

```
declare -g MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT=0
```

...or just stop using it altogether in favor of a simple assignment:

```
MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT=0
```

One needs to do likewise when generating code (and should always use `printf %q` to ensure that one is generating eval-safe output -- also, note the deliberate lack of shebang when writing a file intended to be sourced rather than executed):

```
printf 'MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT=%q\n' "$incremented" > "$count_file_path.$$" \
  && mv -- "$count_file_path.$$" "$count_file_path"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are invoking your function but it seems likely the environment value is not what you think it is. You could try printing the value of `MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT` before you update the file.

---

An alternative approach that doesn't use environment variables and should be safe against multiple simultaneous invocations (your code has a read-modify-write race) but is a bit more cpu-intensive could be to use `sqlite`.

Initialise a key-value store (use more sensible names):

```
sqlite3 ~/bash/counters.db '
    create table t (k,v);
    insert into t values("MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT",0);
'
```

To update:

```
sqlite3 ~/bash/counters.db '
    update t set v=v+1 where k="MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT";
'
```

To read a value:

```
sqlite3 ~/bash/counters.db '
    select v from t where k="MY_LDAP_MY_FUNCTION_COUNT";
'
```

These can be parameterised and assigned to shell functions or scripts.